# How can I save user's setting for notifications laravel5 and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, laravel-5.1

I am building Restful Api for a mobile application. I need to push the notification to user if he has saved the notification setting to true in his profile.

I have created the following structure:

**Users Table:**

<kbd>id</kbd> <kbd>name</kbd> <kbd>email</kbd>

<kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>Test</kbd> <kbd>test@test.com</kbd>

<kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>Test1</kbd> <kbd>test1@test1.com</kbd>

**Notifications Table:**

<kbd>id</kbd> <kbd>notification_name</kbd>

<kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>Like Notification</kbd>

<kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>Comment Notification</kbd>

**user_notification Table:**

<kbd>id</kbd> <kbd>notification_id</kbd> <kbd>user_id</kbd> <kbd>value (0=off, 1=on)</kbd>

<kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>1</kbd>                 <kbd>1</kbd>         <kbd>0</kbd>

<kbd>2</kbd>             <kbd>2</kbd>            
     <kbd>1</kbd>         <kbd>1</kbd>

<kbd>3</kbd>             <kbd>1</kbd>                 <kbd>1</kbd>         <kbd>1</kbd>

<kbd>4</kbd>             <kbd>2</kbd>            
     <kbd>1</kbd>         <kbd>1</kbd>

In the above table structure I have created a pivot table with an extra field `value` for saving settings of a user.

**Is there any another great way to do this, in which I can minimize my queries and respond fast**

Comment: What's with the kbd prefix???

Comment: I did not know how to show table in question, that is why I have used kbd for formatting

Comment: SO has a code button '{}' that indents text by 4 spaces. Indented text is rendered as monospaced code

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll remember this for future

Comment: If you have only 100 users, MySQL will be fast enough without any redesign.

Comment: @Rick James I can not control the users they can be 100 or can be 1 million

Answer (score 1):

Your pivot table should only contain the two references defined, `notification_id` and `user_id`. Adding more fields to that negates it as a pivot table.

You shpuld put the `value` field on your `notifications` table instead, perhaps naming it better like `is_active`. It is your notification that has a setting, right? So it makes sense that the setting goes on the notification, not the pivot table which only serves to connect the two tables.

Also, as a sugestion, have your pivot table alphabetical as per normal convention in Laravel ([see the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many))

In your `User.php` model, add the relationship

```
public function notifications() {
    return $this->hasMany(App\Notification::class, 'notification_user');
}
```

When querying this relationship, all you have to do is:

```
foreach($user->notifications as $notification) {
    if($notification->is_active) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please explain me the `notifications` function in `User.php` what is the `notification_user` here?

Comment: `notification_user` is your `user_notification` table. I switched the two around to follow the alphabetical practice for pivot tables. As for the relationship. When you have many to many relationships (a notification has many users, and a user has many notifications), you add as the second argument to the `hasMany` method, the pivot table.
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many